# Linux: Set Variable to Value following regex pattern, without quotes, in a single command (no pipes) in most compatible way possible

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I need to grab a value from a config file (config.toml) and store it to a system variable.

I prefer to use a single command without pipes in the most compatible way possible (across linux systems)

Should return `https://www.example.com` with the config file set any of these ways:

```
base_url="https://www.example.com"
base_url = "https://www.example.com"
base_url  =  "https://www.example.com"
```

The solution I have so far based on some research is the following:

```
baseurl="$(sed -n -E 's/^base_url.*=\s+?\"//p' config.toml)"
echo $baseurl
```

My solution still has the trailing quotation mark, I have not yet figured out how to deal with it.

The other problem is I am not certain that this is the most universal solution. I prefer to use something that will work universally on most linux systems.

Appreciate all feedback, Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different implementations of `sed` understand different types of regex. Only [BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) is portable:

```
sed -n 's/^base_url[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' config.toml
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it. Bookmarked that page too!

Answer (score 0):

Edit, based on @jhnc feedback. I now use this:

```
baseurl="$(sed -n -E 's/^base_url.*=.*"(.*)"/\1/p' config.toml)"
echo $baseurl
```

I am still not sure if some Linux systems might run into issues with this or not.

If anyone sees an issue with this solution or has a more universally compatible solution please let me know.

Comment: `\s` and `+?` are not portable

Comment: `"` does not need to be escaped with `\\`

Comment: @jhnc I was worried about the +? Please let me know if there is a better solution.  Maybe I should just use .* assuming the quotes will always be there!